# iis as reverse proxy: configure it to forward current windows loged user as a custom header

Tags: node.js, authentication, iis, reverse-proxy, windows-authentication

I have a node rest web service that is being served with IIS as reverse proxy

I wonder if there's some way to configure iis to add a custom header with the current loged in user, just like it does with the `x-forwarded-for` header

I just need to get the current authenticated user (windows integrated secutiry, via ntlm) to the node app.

I though that telling iis to forward that info would be the easiest path, but any other solution would be welcome

Answer (score 1):

You could probably try promoting the IIS server variable for authenticated user (AUTH_USER) to iisnode Header and consume that on the node app.

So on IIS,

```
<configuration>                                                     
     .......
   <system.webServer>
      <iisnode promoteServerVars="AUTH_USER" />    
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Which then on the node end,

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var username = req.headers['x-iisnode-auth_user'];  
}).listen(process.env.PORT);
```

There are other IIS server variables that can be promoted and can be found [here:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms524602(v=vs.90))

Comment: I wonder if it's possible to achieve such a thing without using iisnode