# IIS Reverse Proxy with Windows Authentication and user name forwarding

Tags: iis, kerberos, windows-authentication, ntlm

I need to connect legacy client systems doing Windows Authentication to a new backend that cannot participate in Windows Authentication.

For this purpose, I'm planning to use IIS, configure Windows Authentication, and adding Application Request Routing to create a reverse proxy.

This works well, however, I need the destination server to also get the user name established during authentication, added in a header field like `X-LOGON-USER` or similar. I set up URL Rewrite to add this header, but the server variables like LOGON_USER or AUTH_USER appear to be empty.

What's the right approach to forward the user name to the destination server?

Comment: ARR merely passes the requests to the destination server and does not perform any authentication itself. That's why on that ARR/IIS server you get no user information. You will have to look for a third party proxy if you do want user name forwarding.

Comment: Similar questions you can use as a reference: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/57873652/13336642](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57873652/13336642).